# How to translate controller member arrays in Ember-i18n?

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

In my customer controller I have defined some constant arrays that are used for populating select input (dropdown) options.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    occupations: [
        {code: 'student', name: "Student"},
        {code: 'worker', name: "Worker"},
        {code: 'retired', name: "Retired"},
        {code: 'other', name: "Other"}
    ]
});
```

Normal solution would be using translationMacro function t() or this.get('i18n').t() around translation key, but they can't be used in such situation as "this" inside object or array will not refer to controller.

What is best practice for solving such situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make `occupations` a property:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    i18n: Ember.inject.service(),

    occupations: function() {
        var i18n = this.get('i18n');
        return [
            {code: 'student', name: i18n.t('occupations.student') },
            {code: 'worker', name: "Worker"},
            {code: 'retired', name: "Retired"},
            {code: 'other', name: "Other"}
        ];
    }.property()
});
```

Comment: What's the difference betweeen injecting and importing? I mean normal usecase would be to import { getI18n } from 'xx/utils/i18n';